# Subversion & Trac : Age column displaying "48 years" after upgrading to 1.2.2 + Empty Author & Last change

Tags: svn, trac

We recently changed our development server, and upgraded from Trac 0.12.2 to Trac 1.2.2.

But now, for all our files and directories, the "Age" column shows "48 years" (it thinks that the file/directly was last modified on 1970-01-01), the "Author" and the "Last change" column are empty ([screen capture](https://trac.edgewall.org/attachment/ticket/12960/Trac%20after%20update.jpg)).

The subversion directory didn't change at all.

Here is also the result of the `svnadmin info`:

```
 - Path: /home/svn/dreamzer
 - UUID: c3c44155-e6a2-4be4-b891-ff6d4754e42b
 - Repository Format: 5
 - Compatible With Version: 1.9.0
 - Repository Capability: mergeinfo
 - Filesystem Type: fsfs
 - Filesystem Format: 7
 - FSFS Sharded: yes
 - FSFS Shard Size: 1000
 - FSFS Shards Packed: 0/39
 - FSFS Logical Addressing: no
 - Configuration File: /home/svn/dreamzer/db/fsfs.conf
```

And the result of `svn —version`:

```
 - root@dev:~# svn —version
 - svn, version 1.9.5 (r1770682)
```

Thank you everyone for your valuable help!

Comment: In fact, I can't even display the content of any file, I get an error message:  
"Error: No such changeset
No changeset XXXX in the repository"  

I can see the differences between 2 revisions, but I can't display the whole content of any file.

Comment: You probably need to resync the repository. See reply in the [issue you reported](https://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/12960#comment:7).